# Writing a complex REGEX for find and replace in VS2012

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, automata

I want to find and replace a sort of repetitive strings in my project.
I want to use the VS2012 find and replace to make my task easy.

The original string is

```
Format(Element[Be], Element[Be])

 and I want to replace it following

Element[Be].ToString(Element[Be].Value)
```

How that can be done using FindAndReplaace feature of **VS2012 using REGEX**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
Format\(([^,]*),\s*([^\)]*)\)
```

and the following replacement string:

```
$1.ToString($2.Value);
```

in C#:

```
var input = "Format(Element[Be], Element[Be])";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"Format\(([^,]*),\s*([^\)]*)\)", "$1.ToString($2.Value)");
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP7nF2)